# Best way to link Redmine issue to SVN revision

Tags: svn, bug-tracking, redmine

We are using Redmine for issue and bug tracking.  We added SVN integration but, by doing this, it just shows SVN revisions in activity.

It would be great to see all SVN changes caused by a bug or issue.  But it does not seem to be possible.

Is there a way to do that?  If not Redmine, which is the best alternative tracking system to achieve this?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

We add the issue number in svn commit message and it's recognized automatically.

```
svn ci -m "incorrect encoding fixed (refs #2345)"
```

Later you'll be able to see it in the issue #2345. It doesn't show up right away, I guess redmine checks periodically for repository changes - but if you go to `Repository` tab and then to the issue, the change should be shown then.

More info about [Redmine formatting](http://www.redmine.org/wiki/redmine/RedmineTextFormatting)

**==edit==**
To answer Jonas comment:

In fact the idea of this is to be able to make connection between some issue and svn revisions related to it. It should work both ways - in repository page you see the link to the issue; **in the issue's page you should be able to see the link to the related revisions**.

For this to work you need:

- to have configured repository in your project (or parent project, it works as well)
- to have configured keywords like `refs` in Administration->Settings [Repository] ->"Referencing keywords"
- when you commit to svn (mentioning your issue in commit description like "refs #1234"), this revision doesn't appear automatically in redmine repository - you need to refresh it manually going to Repository tab of the project (it's possible to make it automatic with some cron jobs).

After all this you should be able to see in your issue "Associated revisions"

Comment: Awesome reply, thanks!  Excellent stuff that Redmine formatting reference, sorry for being such a Redmine-ignorant...

Comment: Regarding Dmitry Yudakovs answer above:
As far as I can see, you get a link in the Redmine repository-page to the issue, but there is no way to get a link from the issue to all SVN commits where this issue is referenced. Is there a way to get the link the other way, from issue to SVN commits?

Comment: Just maybe you know - what rights should redmine/svn user have to autoclose issues?..

Comment: @Andrey I haven't tried it, sorry. I guess your svn user should correspond (have the same name or the matching to be configured somehow) to the redmine user that has rights to close issues.

Comment: @DmitryYudakov thanks. It appears that my problem with autoclose wasn't related to user permissions. It was custom field "Resolution" that should be filled when autoclose, and it wasn't filled.

Answer (score 8):

For posterity:

If the original commit message did not reference a Redmine issue number, you can also do the reverse: manually reference a repository revision by number in a Redmine issue description.

For example:

> This issue is an unintended side effect of r5678, which was implemented to address issue #1234.

In that case, "r5678" would automatically link to the revision in Redmine's repository tab (and "#1234" would automatically link to the corresponding issue page).

Answer (score 3):

refs allows you to associate a revision to an issue, which is great.

You can also configure another keywords like "fixes" which will associate the revision to an issue, but will also change the status and the % of realisation automatically.

This can be very useful for example when the commit is done to put the issue in a test status. (that will be automatic, without having to do it manually

you can do it 
administration->settings->repositories
and "resolution keywords"