# How to link SVN username and Redmine username while fixing issues with commit message?

Tags: redmine

I'm using Redmine to track issues on my projects. I'm using the feature that [references and closes issues with commit messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3607590/best-way-to-link-redmine-issue-to-svn-revision), which works well except that Redmine can't link my SVN username (which is my linux account on the server), and my redmine username.

My SVN repository is modified by the login `bicou` using the `svn+ssh://` scheme, and my Redmine login is `benoit`. Is there a way to link the two?

The issue is that if I close an issue with a commit message, Redmine indicates that the issue was closed by `Anonymous`...

*I guess this is not the kind of question for Stack Overflow... My apologies if this wasn't.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redmine allows to map redmine user logins to cvs user names as described in the manual: [**Repository user-mapping**](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineRepositories#Repository-user-mapping)

Of course it's easier to use the same user names from the start to have redmine map it automatically...

Comment: Thanks. This was well hidden! :)